# QueryDict returning strange value in Django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've just started working on my first large-scale Django project, I'm currently noodling around with a couple of API's, and one makes a request  using the Python 'requests' library to the following view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def s0003_view(request):
    p = request.POST
    print(p)
    obj = p.get('jsonobj')
    print(obj)
```

The QueryDict object is at 'p' is as follows:

```
<QueryDict: {'jsonobj': ['register_id', 'meter_id', 'id', 'reading_date', 'reading_value', 'meter_point_number', 'pattern', 'reading_method']}>
```

However once I access the 'jsonobj' using p.get() and print its contents, it only returns the final item in the list:

```
reading_method
```

Why is this occuring?
I'm genuinely stumped, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to convert QueryDict into a Python dict?

Comment: Of course! I was looking for an explanation to the behavior, not a solution! :)

Comment: hope the answer below is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation of Django , in a QueryDict Object , there are two methods for fetching values: `get(key)` and `__getitem__(key)`.
when you call one of those methods to get the value of a key ,  if that key contains more than one value , the last value will be returned.

Check out the documentation for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: This does not anwer the question of why this behavior exists. My understanding is that the behavior is good for capturing all information passed in a GET request (through URL parameters) but still returning the most relevant value (the last one). In the context of a POST request where you are passing an array of value to your backend, the mechanism kind of interferes with the purpose and you have to take it into account. Typically, passing all the selected values of a <select> field through a POST and using get() to fetch the values will only return the last one.